# Integration Doctrine 1.2 with Zend framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2, doctrine-1.2

I tried to integrate Doctrine 1.2 in Zend 2 by myself;

but in the FamilleController.php i have this error :

```
Fatal error: Class 'Famille\Controller\Doctrine_Core' not found in 
C:\server\www\test1\module\Famille\src\Famille\Controller\FamilleController.php
on line 21
```

Doctrine_Core is not found !!

how to add Doctrine_ to namespaces of mysite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify where `Doctrine_Core` is located. The controller looks for it in `Famille\Controller`. Just add `use` to the top of the controller file:

```
use Doctrine_Core
```

or use a backslash:

```
\Doctrine_Core
```

Comment: I need to add this use in every controller ? there is no other way to autoload this namespace ?

Comment: oooh this work perfectly. thank you for this quick response. i was blocked for more than 1hour.

Comment: In short: yes, you have to. Otherwise, you can use a backslash: ``\Doctrine_Core``.